# Wordpress: exclude featured image via attr

Tags: wordpress, gallery

i'm aware of the answer provided before with similar question here on SO, but i'm stuck at a few gallery plugins that ignored the "exclude" in the gallery shortcode. Both of them have this line in their php:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ASC, ID ASC',
    'id' => $post->ID,
    'itemtag' => 'dl',
    'icontag' => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns' => 3,
    'size' => 'thumbnail',
), $attr));
```

which i suspect just include the 'exclude' with stuff like this (from other SO answers):

```
 if (!isset($attr['exclude']) || empty($attr['exclude']))
    $attr['exclude'] = array($thumbnail_ID);
elseif (is_array($attr['exclude']))
    $attr['exclude'][] = $thumbnail_ID;
```

but it doesnt work... can anyone please help? this question already caused me several sleepless nights and flu... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is a bit vague to me , and I fail to understand exactly what you want - but anyhow try to add the parameters for include and exlude :

```
'include'    => '',
'exclude'    => ''
```

in your case

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ASC, ID ASC',
    'id' => $post->ID,
    'itemtag' => 'dl',
    'icontag' => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns' => 3,
    'size' => 'thumbnail',
    'include'    => '', //  ID to include or ..
    'exclude'    => '' //  ID to exlude or ..
), $attr));
```

now - as I said, the question is a bit vague as to what you try to achive , for example ,where and how do you set the exlude / inlcude parameters , inside the shortcode itself 
Like -  [gallery include="23,39,45"] / [gallery exlude="X,Y,Z"] or via an interfaced plugin ? .